# sql query for searching with multiple criteria using mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hi I am new in PHP developing and i am trying to make a search in a website and would like to have several search terms which is input by the user to perform db search, terms as below:

- Sex
- Status
- State
- Country

  Here is script to perform search with above term's input:

  ```
  $m_ton=$_REQUEST[m_ton];
  $user_sex=$_REQUEST[user_sex];
  $user_status=$_REQUEST[user_status];
  $user_country=$_REQUEST[user_country];
  $user_state=$_REQUEST[user_state];
  $user_city=$_REQUEST[user_city];
  $religion=$_REQUEST[religion];
  $age=$_REQUEST[age];

  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE ';
  $where = array();

  if (!empty($m_ton)) {
      $where[] = 'm_ton = ' . addslashes($m_ton) . '';
  }

  if (!empty($user_sex)) {
      $where[] = 'user_sex = "' . addslashes($user_sex) . '';
  }
  $sql .= implode(' AND ',$where);

       $rs=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    while($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($rs))
    {
  ```

Comment: ok - but what is the question?

Comment: Dear Ram it is not working

Comment: well - I can see some errors in the code. Have you checked your error logs? And, if I don't mention it someone else most likely will - the `mysql_` suite of functions are deprecated and their use is highly discouraged because of the likely abuse of sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you will have errors in your logs relating to undeclared constants - the `$_REQUEST` variables require the variable name to be quoted - unless they are actually declared as constants.. so they should look more like:-

```
$m_ton=$_REQUEST['m_ton'];
$user_sex=$_REQUEST['user_sex'];
$user_status=$_REQUEST['user_status'];
$user_country=$_REQUEST['user_country'];
$user_state=$_REQUEST['user_state'];
$user_city=$_REQUEST['user_city'];
$religion=$_REQUEST['religion'];
$age=$_REQUEST['age'];
```

The where clauses need quotes around the values as they appear to be strings.. so:-

```
$where[] = 'm_ton = "' . addslashes($m_ton) . '"';
and
$where[] = 'user_sex = "' . addslashes($user_sex) . '"';
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table WHERE m_ton = "1" AND user_sex = "Female' at line 1

Comment: you need to use quotes around the values

Comment: Dear Ram sir i am fresher at php and mysql so i don't know anything.I am making a project on Matrimonial website got from my college so i need your suggestion what should I use in this project and how?

Comment: Please help and give your suggestion.